# Magento 2 : event observer before customer edit form save

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom

> I want to fire event observer before customer account edit details are
> saved, i am unable to find event observer for it.
>
> Is there any observer like customer_account_edited_before.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you don't have such an observer. But depending on your requirement you can try to hook in to `customer_save_before` event and check there if the request comes from a specific controller action (for example `customer/account/editPost`), if you want to restrict your code only to specific action(s).
In that case the observer could look somehow like this:

```
class CustomerEditSaveObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ){

        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Get the name of current module, controller and action
        $moduleName     = $this->request->getModuleName(); 
        $controllerName = $this->request->getControllerName(); 
        $actionName     = $this->request->getActionName();

        if ( $moduleName == 'customer' && $controllerName = 'account' && $actionName == 'editPost') {
            //put your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on what you want to do it may also be better to use a before plugin to an appropriate method of the customer model (plugin method `beforeBeforeSave` or `beforeSave`) and implement there the check for the action or actions you want to